# How to scp files from a ssh cli to my local computer

Tags: bash, shell, scp, remote

Machine: MacOS 11.6

I'm using ssh to enter the command line interface of my remote machine, and I'd like to scp files there to my local machine.

I got my local IP address using `ifconfig`, say it's `aaa.bbb.c.ddd`, and in the remote machines' cli I ran:

`scp ./* myname@aaa.bbb.c.ddd:~/`

And the scp command hanged for a while, and gave:

```
ssh: connect to host aaa.bbb.c.ddd port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

I've already turned on the remote login of my local machine.

```
❯ sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin
Password:
Remote Login: On
```

Is there a way to work around this? Note that I only want to run `scp` from the remote machine's cli. Thanks!

Comment: Have you enabled the `sshd` service on your local machine and opened up the host firewall to port 22?

Comment: @doneal24 I think so:
`❯ sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin
Password:
Remote Login: On`

Comment: Is your desktop on the same network as the server. If not, are you behind a firewall like a home router? Try `tracepath aa.bb.c.ddd` to confirm.

Comment: @doneal24 My local machine is not in the same network with my remote machine.  I ran this on my local machine:
`traceroute to aaa.bbb.c.ddd (aaa.bbb.c.ddd), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  aaa.bbb.c.ddd (aaa.bbb.c.ddd)  1.384 ms  0.181 ms  0.095 ms`

Comment: @IsaIkari Wait, they're not on the same network, but `traceroute` claims to get there on the first hop? Something's weird here. Is your computer using a private IP address (i.e. something with a `10.` prefix, or `192.168.` or maybe `172.16-31.`)? If it is, you won't be able to reach it from anywhere outside that private network without doing something with the router.

Comment: Since comment are not permanent and adding extra information in comments makes the post hard to follow, can you edit your question to add in the diagnostics?